# Python argparse get all parameters after specific flag as list

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to make argparser like in gdb

```
program.py --valid-arg1  value1  --valid-arg2  value2  --args binary --bin-arg1 bin_arg1_value --bin-arg2 bin_arg2_value...
```

The problem is I need treat all arguments after `--args` just as values, and get them as a list inside my program. How can I do that?

Thanks

P.S. Use all unrecognized arguments it's bad solution because python and binary args may have same signature.

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to retrieve `args` as `['binary', '--bin-arg1', 'bin_arg1_value', '--bin-arg2', 'bin_arg2_value']`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what he wants

Comment: @AlexHall yes, something like that

Comment: Can anybody explain why somebody downvoted this question?

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing - what do you think of using `--` instead of `--args`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `sys.argv` instead of `argparse`? You can do something like that then:

```
import sys

dict = {}
tmp = []
key = ''
for arg in sys.argv:
    if arg[0] == '-':
        if tmp != []:
            dict[key] = tmp
            tmp = []
        key = arg
        if key == '--args':
            dict[key] = sys.argv[sys.argv.find(key)+1:]
            break
        continue
    tmp.append(arg)
```

This basically constructs an argument dictionary with flags as keys and list of arguments to flags as values. You might want to check what `sys.argv` is. If you invoke your python script with

```
python script.py -h yes -f yes no yes
```

`sys.argv` might be `['python', 'script.py', '-h', ...]` but I am leaving that to you to find out. Then instead of `for arg in sys.argv` you want to do `for arg in sys.argv[2:]` or something you want.

---

So if we call

```
program.py --valid-arg1  value1  --valid-arg2  value2  --args binary --bin-arg1 bin_arg1_value --bin-arg2 bin_arg2_value
```

the `dict` will look like this:

```
dict = {
    '--valid-arg1': ['value1'],
    '--valid-arg2': ['value2'],
    'args': ['binary', '--bin-arg1', 'bin_arg1_value', '--bin-arg2', 'bin_arg2_value']
}
```

Now if you want to use what is the value for `--valid-arg1`, you can do something like

```
try:
    if dict['--valid-arg1'] == some_value1:
        ...
    elif dict['--valid-arg1'] == some_value2:
        ...
except KeyError:
    # no flag --valid-arg1
    pass
```

With `args` you can do something like

```
try:
    if something in dict['args']:
        ...
except KeyError:
    # no additional args were given
    pass
```

Comment: May I know why and who downvoted this? Don't just downvote, comment why you don't like it...

Comment: The question is about argparse, which is much easier to use than manually parsing argv and has many useful features.

Comment: @AlexHall Much easier to use? Now let me see you use argparse to do what this guy wants...

Comment: It works.

I can split sys.argv on two parts - before --args and after. First part can be parsed by argparse, and second can be used as is.

But it seems that all work can be done by argparse.

Comment: I also would like to know how to extract the values from argparse.args as a list or dict. Why? Because I want to modify them and send them to subprocess.Poepn but I also need to use them and want to use them as argparse allows.